# Trouble with Bagging and OOB assignment

Tags: machine-learning

I am doing a ML course, it is my first course, I am new to ML, and I have been doing some assignments. I have issues with one of them on bagging and OOB
I have to fill the lines in the code below. This is a simplified version of BaggingRegressor from sklearn. Please, notice, that sklearn API is not preserved.
The algorithm should be able to train different instances of the same model class on bootstrapped datasets and to provide OOB score for the training set.

The model should be passed as model class with no explicit parameters and no parentheses.
While I kind of got the _generate_splits() function, I am still struggling with the rest of them.
Can someone tell me what would be the formulas for these functions?

`import numpy as np`

`class SimplifiedBaggingRegressor:

```
def __init__(self, num_bags, oob=False):
    self.num_bags = num_bags
    self.oob = oob
    
def _generate_splits(self, data: np.ndarray):
    '''
    Generate indices for every bag and store in self.indices_list list
    '''
    self.indices_list = []
    data_length = len(data)
    for bag in range(self.num_bags):
        # Your Code Here
                  bag_indices = list(range(0,total_samples))
        self.indices_list.append(bag_indices)
    
def fit(self, model_constructor, data, target):
    '''
    Fit model on every bag.
    Model constructor with no parameters (and with no ()) is passed to this function.
    
    example:
    
    bagging_regressor = SimplifiedBaggingRegressor(num_bags=10, oob=True)
    bagging_regressor.fit(LinearRegression, X, y)
    '''
    self.data = None
    self.target = None
    self._generate_splits(data)
    assert len(set(list(map(len, self.indices_list)))) == 1, 'All bags should be of the same length!'
    assert list(map(len, self.indices_list))[0] == len(data), 'All bags should contain `len(data)` number of elements!'
    self.models_list = []
    for bag in range(self.num_bags):
        model = model_constructor()
        data_bag, target_bag = # Your Code Here
        self.models_list.append(model.fit(data_bag, target_bag)) # store fitted models here
    if self.oob:
        self.data = data
        self.target = target
    
def predict(self, data):
    '''
    Get average prediction for every object from passed dataset
    '''
    # Your code here

def _get_oob_predictions_from_every_model(self):
    '''
    Generates list of lists, where list i contains predictions for self.data[i] object
    from all models, which have not seen this object during training phase
    '''
    list_of_predictions_lists = [[] for _ in range(len(self.data))]
    # Your Code Here
    
    self.list_of_predictions_lists = np.array(list_of_predictions_lists, dtype=object)

def _get_averaged_oob_predictions(self):
    '''
    Compute average prediction for every object from training set.
    If object has been used in all bags on training phase, return None instead of prediction
    '''
    self._get_oob_predictions_from_every_model()
    self.oob_predictions = # Your Code Here
    
    
def OOB_score(self):
    '''
    Compute mean square error for all objects, which have at least one prediction
    '''
    self._get_averaged_oob_predictions()
    return # Your Code Here`
```

I tried to understand how the original BaggingRegressor class works, but I got a bit confused.